# Remove an array from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrayofarrays

I'm totally new to Javascript. I'm working with data from a business database and I want to remove an array from array of arrays.

I have this array of array:

```
var results = [ [#null, null], ['miglioramento', 30], ['correttiva',45] ];
```

I want to remove the first array: [#null, null] from results because I want to achieve this array:

```
results = [ ['miglioramento', 30], ['correttiva',45] ];
```

How can I do this?

I really thank you in advance!

Comment: `#null` is not a valid syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: The **#** is only to clarification purpose, right?

Comment: Will that `[ null, null ]` array always be the first item within the parent array?

Comment: if you want your result to "achieve this array" then set your result to the array you want...?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first entry of your array is `[null, null]` not `[#null, null]`. This way you are filtering all empty arrays containing only `null` as entries.

`results.filter((arr) => arr.filter((entry) => entry !== null).length);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
const slicedArray = array.slice(1)
console.log(slicedArray)
// print : [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

For inner arrays with only two elements, you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the elements to check whether one of the elements isn't equal to `null`. If this is the case, your filter predicate will return `true`, which will keep the inner array.

```js
const data = [[null, null], ['miglioramento', 30], ['correttiva',45]];

const res = data.filter(([e1, e2]) => e1 !== null || e2 !== null);
console.log(res);
```

If your inner arrays can have more than two elements, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to ensure that *some* element within the inner array is not `null`. If the predicate for `.some()` is true for any element within your inner array, it the return value of `.some()` will also be `true` which will make filter keep the inner array as part of the end result.

```js
const data = [[null, null], ['miglioramento', 30], ['correttiva',45]];

const res = data.filter(
  inner => inner.some(elem => elem !== null)
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function to check if an arry is all null then call it inside a filter function.

```js
var results = [
  [null, null],
  ['miglioramento', 30],
  ['correttiva', 45]
];


const checkNull = arr => arr.every(el => el != null);

const res = results.filter(el => checkNull(el));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
var results = [ [null, null], ['miglioramento', 30], ['correttiva',45] ]
results.shift()
console.log(results)
```

Comment: That will only work when the array of nulls is the first element